# isc.php library in to php foreach

Tags: php, loops, foreach, icalendar

I'm using [ics.php](https://gist.github.com/jakebellacera/635416) and it's works fine with one event, but how can I add multiple events from database? How can I loop this:

```
$ics = new ICS(array(
 'id' => $event->id,
 'location' => 'Mājās',
 'description' => $event->description,
 'dtstart' => $event->startdate,
 'dtend' => $event->startdate,
 'summary' => $event->title,
 'url' => '',
 'alarm' => ''
));
echo $ics->to_string();
```

but no looping all class but only events:

```
'id' => $event->id,
'location' => 'Mājās',
'description' => $event->description,
'dtstart' => $event->startdate,
'dtend' => $event->startdate,
'summary' => $event->title,
'url' => '',
'alarm' => ''
```

Answer (score 0):

`ics.php` only supports a single event. If you wish to create a ICS fie with multiple events you will probably have to build the file yourself.

Luckily the file format is very simple so building your own should not be too hard.

A place to start is the output you get from `ics.php`, and then try to recreate it yourself. An ICS file can have multiple event blocks, so just repeat that block a couple of times and you are set.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
...
BEGIN:VEVENT
...
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
...
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: online validator says:Missing VCALENDAR object near line # 1

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to second question**

You have a few errors in your code.

First: You are using single quotes in combination with `\r\n`. `\r\n` is only evaluated when you use double quotes.

Second: You are trying to use `\r\n` in combination with literal newlines in your string declaration. This would produce empty lines in your target file

`$cal = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n
VERSION:2.0\r\n";` as opposed to `$cal = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\nVERSION:2.0\r\n";`

Which will respectively result in

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR

VERSION:2.0
```

and

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
```

Updated code:

```
$events = ORM::for_table('events')->find_many();

$cal = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n";
$cal .= "VERSION:2.0\r\n";
$cal .= "PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN\r\n";
$cal .= "CALSCALE:GREGORIAN\r\n";

foreach($events as $event){
    $cal .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n";
    $cal .= "STATUS:CONFIRMED\r\n";
    $cal .= "UID:" . $event->id . "\r\n";
    $cal .= "LOCATION:\r\n";
    $cal .= "DESCRIPTION:" . $event->description . "\r\n";
    $cal .= "SUMMARY:" . $event->title . "\r\n";
    $cal .= "DTSTART:" . $event->startdate . "\r\n";
    $cal .= "DTEND:" . $event->startdate . "\r\n";
    $cal .= "LAST-MODIFIED:\r\n";
    $cal .= "END:VEVENT\r\n";
}
$cal .= "END:VCALENDAR\r\n";

echo $cal;
```

update:

changed '$cal .= "END:VEVENT";' to '$cal .= "END:VEVENT\r\n";'

Comment: Mismatched 'BEGIN' and 'END' (BEGIN:VEVENT, END:VEVENTBEGIN:VEVENT) near line # 14
Missing DTSTAMP property near line # 5
Reference: RFC 5545 3.6.1. Event Component
Invalid DTSTART value, must be a date or date-time value near line # 5
Reference: 3.3.5. Date-Time
Invalid DTEND value, must be a date or date-time value near line # 5
Reference: 3.3.5. Date-Time